# Retrieving enum from ListBox SelectedItems property

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, enums

I have an Enum defined, my intention is to display the four options(None, Left, Center, and Right) to a user in a ListBox. This ListBox will allow for multiple selections. When the save command is clicked I must pass the selections to the ViewModel where I will aggregate the selections and pass this to a WCF service.

**Enum:**

```
[DataContract]
[Flags]
public enum Locations
{
    None = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    Left = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    Center = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    Right = 4,
    [EnumMember]
    LeftCenter = Left | Center,
    [EnumMember]
    LeftRight = Left | Right,
    [EnumMember]
    CenterRight = Center | Right,
    [EnumMember]
    All = Left | Center | Right
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=lbLocations}" />
<ListBox x:Name="lbLocations" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListBoxItem Content="{x:Static m:Subsections.None}" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="{x:Static m:Subsections.Left}" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="{x:Static m:Subsections.Center}" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="{x:Static m:Subsections.Right}" />
</ListBox>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public ICommand SaveCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_saveCommand == null)
            _saveCommand = new RelayCommand<IList>(x => Save(x));

         return _saveCommand;
    }
}

private void Save(IList locations)
{
    try
    {
        // ToList() produces InvalidCastException.
        var collection = locations.Cast<Locations>().ToList();

        // Do WCF stuff, display success, etc.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _dialogService.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
}
```

I have successfully passed the selections back to my ViewModel as an IList, but I'm having difficulty casting it back to my enum. Is there a better approach I have overlooked, can this work? It seems like I'm nearly there.

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating through the casted list and aggregating the value into a single variable, like this:

```cs
private void Save(IList locations)
{
    try
    {
        Locations location = Locations.None;

        foreach (Locations value in locations.Cast<Locations>())
        {
            location |= value;
        }

        // Do WCF stuff, display success, etc.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _dialogService.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: The foreach loop throws the same InvalidCastException as ToList().

Comment: Then it is the `Cast<T>()` call what throws the exception, not the `ToList()`?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the `IList`? What does it contain? Have you tried `OfType<T>()` instead of `Cast<T>()`?

Comment: Correct the act of casting is throwing the exception, but I believe due to the nature of IEnumerable's you won't see an exception unless you iterate via ToList or foreach?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, too. But the exception itself makes me think that your `IList` doesn't contain objects of type `Locations`, or at least not all of the objects inside are of that type... If it's just a matter of some rogue item, maybe using `OfType<T>()` would be enough.

Comment: That put me on the right track, the IList contained ListBoxItem's, I would have thought that abstraction would have been handled for me as I believe ListBoxItems are still the default template for items bound to ItemsSource? In any case locations.Cast<ListBoxItem>().Select(x => x.Content) got me going, but I'm evaluating Glen's solution as well.

Comment: The `Items` property of an `ItemsControl` always returns the same you assign to it, even if it internally manages it to wrap the items or not around containers. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to achieve this:

Create a class to hold data for each item in the `ListBox`

```
class EnumSelection
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public Subsections Value { get; set; }

    public EnumSelection(Subsections value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` to the available enums

```
private IEnumerable<EnumSelection> enums;
public IEnumerable<EnumSelection> Enums
{
    get
    {
        if (this.enums == null)
        {
            this.enums = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Subsections)).Cast<Subsections>().Select(s => new EnumSelection(s));
        }

        return this.enums;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<EnumSelection> SelectedItems
{
    get
    {
        return Enums.Where(e => e.IsSelected);
    }
}
```

Use a DataTemplate to bind to the new class

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Enums}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Save method:

```
ICommand _saveCommand;
public ICommand SaveCommand
{
    get
    {
        return this._saveCommand
               ?? (this._saveCommand = new RelayCommand<IEnumerable<EnumSelection>>(x => this.Save(x)));
    }
}

private void Save(IEnumerable<EnumSelection> enums)
{
}
```